# React-native, Navigate previous page with deeplink

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

My problem is when i use dynamiclink and navigate to my home page,  i click button to go next page but automatically go back home page.

deleting deeplink from redux is solving issue. However, I need  deeplink to use other pages

Which logic should i use to handle this ?